# Ruby lexical scope inside iterator block

Tags: ruby, scope, iterator, block

In Ruby (v2.5.0)...

```
[1,2,3].map do |i|
  if i.eql?(3)
    a = 123
  end
  defined?(a)
end
=> ["local-variable", "local-variable", "local-variable"]
```

Can someone please explain to me how `a` can be a `local-variable` (equal to `nil`) in the first and second iteration, if it's not set until the third iteration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question can be simplified to `if false; a = 42; end; defined?(a)`.

Comment: See [Local Variables and Methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods): _"The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer quoting a book by A.Black: *Well Grounded Rubyist*, Chapter 6, p. 158. (second edition 2014):

When the Ruby parser sees the sequence *identifier*, *equal-sign*, and *value*, as in this expression,

`a = 123`

it allocates space for a local variable `a`. The creation of the variable - not the assignment of a value to it, but the internal creation of a variable - always takes place as a result of this kind of expression, event if the code isn't executed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!